# Button image not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I'm total CSS/HTML noob.
I would really appreciate if you help me out.

I need to fix my button:

- decrease activation field (hover) to the actual size of the button (without shadow)
- when I hover cursor over button, how to get rid of 1st image left overs?

THANK YOU!

**jsfiddle link:**

http://jsfiddle.net/cRqhT/125/

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
<a id="button" href="http://mysite.com"</a>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width: 820px;
    height: 820px;
    background: url('https://gator1174.hostgator.com/~mskparik/facebook/thx.jpg')
}

#button{
  display: block;
    width: 204px;
    height: 116px;
    background: url(https://gator1174.hostgator.com/~mskparik/facebook/111.png) no-repeat top left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left:10%;
}
#button:hover {
    background: url(https://gator1174.hostgator.com/~mskparik/facebook/222.png) no-repeat top;
    }
```

Comment: Please try to use a better title to questions. The current one is really not appropriate.

Comment: Please don't use inappropriate language even if it's partially censored, it will only serve to get your questions deleted, check out [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for guidance on acceptable behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, no prob. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply added a corner bracket where appropriate, and it seems to have fixed both problems. See JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cRqhT/126/).

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a id="button" href="http://mysite.com"></a> <!--Notice extra corner bracket-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is where sytax high-lighting can really save you. If it looks funny, something is wrong. Even in your fiddle example, everything after the missing bracket was RED.